# How do I get my old identicon back?

Tags: support

I was going through my profile, and I realised that I had to update my email address. Well, as soon as I did so, my identicon changed to a new one, something I did **not** want at all because I loved my old one and disliked the new one. So is there any way to bring back the old identicon? I could not find this question elsewhere, so if it is there, I apoogize in advance.

By the way, I also saved my changes before noticing the difference, so I could not even cancel the change. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: my post has been tagged as a duplicate, however, that question does not have a defined answer, so I could not get a complete solution out of it. That is why I posted a new question here. Just for clarification so that my question is not closed as a duplicate.

Comment: How long ago did you change it? Here's a cache of your profile from Jan 22, but still the same avatar: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dAND-5sEUfQJ:meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7310344/a-busy-programmer+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: This was not any problem for me. I do not understand why you cannot get your old one back.

Comment: I changed it about half an hour ago, @AlexanderO'Mara.

Comment: I just fixed the peoblem a minute ago, and I guess it took some time for the identicon to update, cause it changed for me immediately. My iPad is kinda slow, if that could be a cause, @yellowantphil.

Comment: Also, @yellowantphil, I saw that post which BMP posted as a duplicate, but it did not answer my question, that's why I posted this one. Thanks for pointing that out as support!

Comment: I dunno, but anyways, thanks for your help, @yellowantphil!

Comment: @Anthon, I have already explained why this is not a duplicate in my post above.

Comment: This site has edit history, so if someone wants to see an older (incomplete) version of a post (questions but also answers) they can go there. If someone uses "Edit" (or "Update", etc) in a post instead of rewriting it into a single coherent whole, and just tacks things on they make it hard on future readers. In such cases I just stop reading out of principle. I am just too busy to do the integration of the text following EDIT(s) and if the OP doesn't care enough to optimize their post for others to read, the OP indicates it is not important.

Comment: @yellowantphil - I figured the OP cared more about "how to get it back" than "why did it change". Had the OP originally stated that none of the existing answers on how to get your old Gravatar back were helpful, I would not have suggested it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably find your old avatar image if you substitute the `806ee9f59ff90ee73cc0e1bfcd08411f` hash in the following URL with the MD5 hash of your old email address ([as Gravatar documents](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/)).

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/806ee9f59ff90ee73cc0e1bfcd08411f?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1
```

This should get the avatar from Gravatar for your old email address. Then you could just upload that image as your avatar.

Of course, changing your email address back could also work, assuming you still have that email address.

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked for me. I took the link from your comments box (it apparently did not update yet, no idea why :/), took a snapshot of the picture, and saved it as my new profile picture. Now I have my old identicon back. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an image of your previous one, you could manually upload that as your gravatar, and that would give you the old image you liked.

At present, the gravatar generated is done automatically based on a hash from your email address. So unless your email is changed again, or you upload an image of your desired gravatar, this is the one you are stuck with.

Comment: Thanks, I used the link alexander posted, but I then used your technique of taking a snapshot of my old identicon, and re-uploading it as a profile picture. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just go to edit profile and settings, then I hover over my picture and hit change picture. Then I have the option of identicon or uploaded image and I click identicon.
I am using iOS by the way.

Comment: The thing is, my old identicon was lost, and it did not show up in your method, even though I use iOS. However, Alexander's and Travis's solution worked fine for me combined. Nevertheless, thanks for your input :-)